Why my website works when I disabled SNI from IIS?
In my company, we have Windows Server 2022. For each website, we use Let's Encrypt certificates. This showed an alert that said: "No default SSL site has been created. To support browsers without SNI capabilities, it is recommended to create a default SSL site." This caused my website not to work. Disabling the option: "Require Server Name Indication" allowed the website to start working. The question is, why does disabling SNI make the website start working?

Your website failed to work because,

The HTTP clients/browsers you use are probably too old to support SNI based SSL/TLS handshakes.
Like "No default SSL site has been created. To support browsers without SNI capabilities, it is recommended to create a default SSL site" indicated, you didn't configure any IP based certificate mapping in Windows HTTP API.

Then for those old clients/browsers, no SSL/TLS connections can be made.
You didn't fix the issue by "disabling SNI", because Windows HTTP API doesn't provide you a way to disable SNI support. All you did is merely create IP based mappings by dismissing "Require Server Name Indication" in IIS Manager dialog.
To learn more about IP based mappings, you can read this article.

Disabling SNI means that the server does not require the client to specify the intended domain name in the TLS handshake. This implicitly creates the "default site" which was requested. Still, disabling SNI only helps if there is only a single domain served by the server or if all domains should be included in the same certificate.

"Disabling SNI means that the server does not require the client to specify the intended domain name in the TLS handshake" is not true, because the server never require the client to specify the intended domain name even if SNI is enabled.

@LexLi: if you have multiple domains with different certificates on the same IP address you need SNI, no way around it. And many sites fail if the client does not support SNI, like everything behind the cloudflare CDN. That's what I consider "sites require SNI".
